# An error occurs when trying to execute a request with JWT "status": 500,

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security

I do authentication with a username and password, after which I receive a token in order to send further requests to change the field in the database.
Registration is successful. Authentication and token acquisition succeeds. When executing requests with a token for a specific user, an NULL error appears. Tell me what could be the problem ? why doesn't it find it in the db?
Perhaps there is a more convenient way to make changes in the database, please tell me.

Error and code:

```
request:
PUT http://localhost:8080/profile/updated/7

{ "description":"hello world"}

response:

{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-16T22:36:57.169+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/profile/updated/7"
}
```

REST CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/profile")
public class UserActController {

    UserServiceActProfile userServiceActProfile;
    
    @Autowired
    public UserActController(UserServiceActProfile userServiceActProfile){

        this.userServiceActProfile=userServiceActProfile;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = { "updated/{id}" },produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
     public ResponseEntity<?> updateDescription (@PathVariable Long id,  @RequestBody  User name ){
        return userServiceActProfile.updateDescription(id,name);
     }
```

SERVICE:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceActProfile {
 
      UserRepository userRepository;

    public ResponseEntity<?> updateDescription(Long id, User ds){
           User user = userRepository.findById(id).get();

           user.setDescription(ds.getDescription());

           userRepository.save(user);


        return ResponseEntity.ok(new MessageResponse("Description update!"));
    }
    
}
```

REPOSITORY:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    
    User findByUsername(String name);
    User findByEmail(String name);

    Optional<User> findById(Long Id);
    
}
```

CONFIG:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    
    private static final String LOGIN_ENDPOINT = "/auth/**";
    
     @Autowired
     private  JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
     
     @Autowired
     private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
     
     @Autowired
     private JwtUserService jwtUserService;
     
         
       @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
       }
     
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http 
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(LOGIN_ENDPOINT).permitAll()       
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .apply(new JwtConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider))
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll();
        
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserService)
                  
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }   
    
}
```

ERROR:

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.op.springboot.repository.UserRepository.findById(java.lang.Long)" because "this.userRepository" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.op.springboot.repository.UserRepository.findById(java.lang.Long)" because "this.userRepository" is null
        at com.op.springboot.service.UserServiceActProfile.updateDescription(UserServiceActProfile.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.op.springboot.controller.UserActController.updateDescription(UserActController.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new NPE error message tells you *exactly what is null and where*. You didn't initialize `userRepository` anywhere; you need a constructor for it just like in your controller (`@Autowired` is not needed if you have only one constructor for a class).

In general, making dependency fields like `userRepository` `final` is a good practice; if you add `final`, the compiler will tell you that you aren't initializing it anywhere.